# Where do I get gedit for windows?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, gedit

Do I just install the binary from here: http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/

Is it simply click to install or?

Do I install python 2 or 3? Or does it matter?

Answer (score 3):

Python isn't involved here...

For gedit you want [the win32 binary.](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/gedit/)